# Cannot find module 'connect' on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: node.js, module, find, node.js-connect

I installed the Connect module using NPM running the following command:

```
npm install connect
```

It created the module in the /Download/usr/node_modules/connect folder. I created a file which uses the Connect module using:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var util = require('util');

function sendjson(res,obj)
{
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'application/json',});

    var objstr = JSON.stringify(obj);
    util.debug('SENDJSON' + objstr);
    res.end(objstr);
} 

var server = connect.createServer(
    connect.router(function(app){

        app.get('/foo', function(req,res){
            sendjson(res,{path:'foo'});
        })
        app.get('/bar', function(req,res){
            sendjson(res,{path:'bar'});
        })
    })
);

 server.listen(3000);
```

I run node createServer.js and it throws in the terminal and it gives me the following error.

> Cannot find module 'connect'

Comment: what folder is createServer.js in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM modules by default need to be installed locally in the folder that contains the source file that uses them. So if your source file is in /Desktop/nodescripts, you should run "npm install connect" in that same folder. That will create node_modules folder in that path, and your script will be able to find it.

Comment: Really thank you for responding. That makes so much sense. So would you suggest to move the /Downloads/node_module folder to /Desktop/nodescripts or would you suggest me to uninstall connect module and reinstall it ?

Comment: Probably best to just reinstall it in that folder.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the Router middleware. This was removed in Connect 2.0. You'll have to use a different router middleware, like https://github.com/baryshev/connect-route or https://github.com/crcn/connect-router  Or you could just use Express, which gives you routing and a lot more.